# Selecting nested iframe - selenium / javascript / node-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, selenium

I want to select a nested iframe within an iframe with the selenium webdriver module in node-js.

For example:

```
<iframe id="firstframe">
   <div id="firstdiv"></div>
   <iframe id="secondframe">
     <div id="seconddiv"></div>
   </iframe>
</iframe>
```

for the node-js part:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("firstframe");   // --> works
driver.switchTo().frame("secondframe");  // --> NoSuchFrameError


iframes = driver.findElements(webdriver.By.tagName('iframe')).then(function(elements){
            console.log(elements.length); // --> if I put this code before the switch to first frame output: 1, if I put it after output: 0)
            });
```

I tried using the index number but this also failed.

Edit:

Ok, I figured it out but my answer got deleted by user @casparOne for some reason. If anyone still wonders what the problem was here goes:

My code above works, just not locally. Chrome's security settings refuse to go deeper in an iframe on a local file. Hence it didn't even show the source code for the iframe.

Comment: Before switching to the `secondframe` try to switch back to default content.

Comment: Getting a `NoSuchFrameError` as well.

Comment: you can use 

driver.switchTo().frame("secondframe");

Answer (score 5):

I've done this kind of thing before a few times.   Try putting a 1 second pause between the swtich frames.  (Sometimes) you need to give Selenium (or the browser) enough time for the frame DOM to load before you try another switch.

Comment: `driver.switchTo().frame("firstframe");`   `setTimeout(function(){driver.switchTo().frame("secondframe");}, 5000);`  still getting `NoSuchFrameError`. I also tried using a `.then()`-promise after the first.

Comment: You can troubleshoot by using XPath to get all elements from the dom matching tag name "iframe".

Comment: What about:

driver.switchTo().frame("firstframe");
driver.sleep("2000");
driver.switchTo().frame("secondframe");

Webdriver js manages selenium promises by using what is called a "Control Flow", basically it's a promises manager (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Control_Flows). Try using "official" waiters instead of setTimeout. In this case driver.sleep should do the job.

Comment: I think that "Control Flow" think you refer to is an older Selenium 1.0 thing?

Comment: I have done similar, it is so weird to use timeouts for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

instead of

```
driver.switchTo().frame("secondframe");
```

, as it is the sole child iframe within the parent.