# Access to iframe using classname

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```html
<iframe class="class_name">
        <html>

          <head></head>

          <body>

            <div>
              <!-- All of the stuff -->
            </div>

          </body>

        </html>
    </iframe>
```

How can I access to elements of this iframe?

> `.frame("class='classname'")`

The above doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Although two iframes have the same class, this will hide only the first iframe.

```js
function hide() {
var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName("iframe");
iframe[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<iframe class="iframe"></iframe>
<iframe class="iframe"></iframe>
<br>
<button onclick="hide()">Hide 1st Iframe</button>
```

**What does this code does?**

`document.getElementsByClassName("iframe")` gets all the elements with the class `iframe` and set the elements as the value of a variable named `iframe`. The number inside `[]` defines one element of the many. If the number inside `[]` is `0`, the first element out of the group of elements is defined. After `[]`, you can set the property you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try with an id

```
<iframe id="your_id">
```

and use

```
.frame('your_id')
```

Comment: But I haven`t got an id, only the classname. Is it impossible to access iframe using only classname?

Answer (score 0):

But here it will not work because of the security policy. Try it on your machine.
Read more about [X-XSS-Protection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection).

```js
var frame = document.querySelector(".myframe");

var content = frame.contentDocument;

console.log(content);
```

```html
<iframe class="myframe" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.weather.gov/" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using nightwatch  - I see you're using .frame() and that is the Nightwatch method for selecting iframes - you cannot switch to an iframe by *class*, but you can use an **index** or by name if the element has a *name* attribute.

These posts should help:

[Can't select an Iframe in selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721263/cant-select-an-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver/25722877#25722877)

[Selecting nested iframe - selenium / javascript / node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401394/selecting-nested-iframe-selenium-javascript-node-js)